# how to integrate amazon s3 oauth 2.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth-2.0

Is there any Oauth 2.0 authentication integration for amazon s3 ? like dropbox ?[dropbox oauth2.0 integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju4yU.png)

If not, is there any other protocol amazon s3 supports?

Answer (score 3):

*This may not be exactly what you're after and it requires a separate App, but since there's no activity on this I thought it's worth mentioning...*

You can sign an S3 request to temporarily allow an anonymous user to access a secure file in S3.

You can secure your App with OAuth2 then the App can generate a secure temporary link which allows the user to download a piece of content directly from S3.

Official documentation: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Sample in PHP: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/generate-expiring-amazon-s3-link/

Another similar method using cloudfront: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html#private-content-overview

Comment: Any updates on this? Specifically integrating with php?